# How to create Agora channel name and token via API from the web server

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I want to create the Agora  https://www.agora.io/en/ channel name and token by using the Agora API in Laravel.
Anyone can help, please.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the [Agora web SDK(JavaScript)](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_web?platform=Web) to accomplish this since there are no laravel SDKs from Agora. You can basically drop all the agora related js code into a `<script>` tag inside your HTML template. Right after the agora import.

```
<script src="https://cdn.agora.io/sdk/release/AgoraRTCSDK-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
// Agora related code goes here
</script>
```

For developing a barebones application, you can read this: https://medium.com/agora-io/video-calling-using-agoras-javascript-sdk-73ba0a315cbd

As far as the token server goes, Agora has a PHP token server implementation here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/token_server_php?platform=PHP